# Как получить цену из регистра сведений?

Tags: 1с

Какие есть возможности по работе с регистром сведений, чтобы получить оттуда данные?

[image]

Comment: Сформулируйте проблему более понятно. Ссылаться зачем? Чтобы было что? Что в итоге вам нужно иметь на выходе решения вашей проблемы?

Comment: мне надо на выходе; что бы ссылался к регистру где цены на услуги  брал цены и вставлял автоматом на услугу которую выбрал

Comment: Всё равно смутно описываете. Старайтесь использовать правила нашего могучего, русского языка. Вам надо цену из регистра получить?

Comment: да надо цену на товар  из регистра

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть два варианта получения данных из РС (регистра сведений):

**1. Объектная модель**

```
Результат = РегистрыСведений.<ИмяРегистра>.ПолучитьПоследнее(<КонецПериода>, <Отбор>);
```

Почитайте о методе в СП (синтакс-помощнике)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2. Запросом.** Используя виртуальную таблицу "СрезПоследних". В моем примере синонимы регистра, измерений, ресурсов могут отличаться, так как брал данные из УТ 11.4.

```
Запрос = Новый Запрос;
Запрос.Текст = 
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
    |   ЦеныНоменклатурыСрезПоследних.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура,
    |   ЦеныНоменклатурыСрезПоследних.Цена КАК Цена
    |ИЗ
    |   РегистрСведений.ЦеныНоменклатуры.СрезПоследних(&Период, ) КАК ЦеныНоменклатурыСрезПоследних";

Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Период", Период);

РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();

ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();

Пока ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Следующий() Цикл
    // Вставить обработку выборки ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи
КонецЦикла;
```